# ILogger.BeginScope(): persisting scope between calls to other methods

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I need to log custom dimensions to `Application Insights` for which I'm using `ILogger.BeginScope()`. That works perfectly. That is:

```
using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { "key": "value" }))
{
    logger.LogInformation("message");
}
```

My issue is that I need to call other methods in other classes, and I'm injecting the `ILogger` into all my classes. **So how can I persist the logging scope among all my classes?**

I could surely do `ILogger.BeginScope()` in all my classes, but I would need to pass the custom properties to classes that don't really need that information. Is there a pattern I could use?

Comment: Maybe using a Scoped Dependency Injection of class that holds the scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `BeginScope` multiple times in multiple classes within the same execution path, you will get one aggregated scope. There is no need to manually pass the properties. `ILogger` is injected as a singleton by default (see [source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,39)).

See also [Since ILogger<T> is a singleton, how different threads can use BeginScope() without affecting others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851259/since-iloggert-is-a-singleton-how-different-threads-can-use-beginscope-with)

> A call to `BeginScope` will put a new item onto that stack, and the adjoining `Dispose` will pop it off of that stack.
>
> When the logger is invoked via `LogInformation` or otherwise, the data of the current stack object will be copied to write it to the console or whatever output that logger instance is configured to do.

- [LoggerExternalScopeProvider.cs#L14](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExternalScopeProvider.cs#L14)

Comment: In my use it appears that when I enter a subsequent call, such as OnAfterRenderAsync, the scope I set earlier has been removed. Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: @DavidThielen I'd have to check the blazor life cycle in more detail. but I'd probably collect all the disposables and only dispose them when the page itself is disposed.

Comment: I came up with a solution that I think works really well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76584828/509627